# Python Regex (Lookaround)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write Python Regex.
First I have read each line of the file into a list.Then I am looping through the list.

Q1. I want to capture when the arithmetic operators does not have space between them.Something like

Capture:

```
a = a+5
```

Does not capture:

```
a = a + 5
```

For this,I have written something like:

```
for i in array:

      pattern = re.search(r"\S(\+|\-|\*|\\)\S",i)
```

\S :           anything other than space

(+|-|*|\):mathematical operators

\S  :           anything other than space

But the problem is,its capturing the lines where post increment operators are used.

Captures :

```
a = a++
```

How could I write a regex expression such that it does not capture the line where post increment operators are used.

Q2.I want to capture where multi line comments are used in a file.

I tried by writing the below expression but it is failing to capture.I don't know where I have done wrong.Kindly help.

```
for i in array:

      pattern = re.search(r"\/\*[A-Za-z0-9_]\*\/",i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1, you want a plus not preceded by a space or a plus and not followed by a space or a plus. This can be written

```
r"(?<![+\s])[+](?![+\s])"
```

You can do the same expression with minus instead of plus, or star, or slash. Then join these expressions with the `|` sign.

For question 2, you can try

```
r"[/][*](?:[^*]|[*](?![/]))*[*][/]"
```

Of course it won't handle nested multiline comments. For these, a simple regex won't suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue can be solved with the help of negated character classes, at least  for the current example strings and maybe some more cases. The problem you showed is due to the fact that `\S` matches any non-whitespace character. To match any char that is not whitespace, `-`, `/`, `+` and `*`, and maybe even `(` and `)`, use `[^\s+*/()-]` negated character class. Your first regex - note that division operator should be `/`, not `\` - can be written as

```
pat = r"[^\s+*/()-]([+*/-])[^\s+*/()-]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhhBKh/2)

The second one is a solved issue.

```
pat = r"/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NhhBKh/3).

**Details**

- `/\*` - comment start
- `[^*]*\*+` - match 0+ characters other than `*` followed with 1+ literal `*`
- `(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[^/*][^*]*\*+` - not a `/` or `*` (matched with `[^/*]`) followed with 0+ non-asterisk characters (`[^*]*`) followed with 1+ asterisks (`\*+`)
- `/` - closing `/`